# creating a histogram using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am extremely new to SQL and wish to create a histogram which should look as the following - 2 columns, one with "z" values, ranging from 0 to 1, with an interval of 0.01, and the second which will include the number of count(z) per each interval. Visually, it should look something like this:

```
      z | count(z)
    -------------
  0-0.01| 12312
```

0.01 - 0.02 | 143565

0.02 - 0.03 | 23445

and so on...

I tried looping, concatinating string and using EXEC, but nothing seems to work :(
the closest I've got to extracting some useful data was by using the following code, which produced a 2D matrix with the first column containing the data and the rest NULL:

```
DECLARE @i float = 0  
WHILE @i < 0.1 
  BEGIN
    exec ('select count(z) as ''' +@i +''' from specObj where z BETWEEN 
' +@i +' and (' +@i +'+0.01)')
    SET @i = @i + 0.01    
  END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to loop.  Just use some arithmetic in the `group by`.  Here is the basic idea:

```
select cast(z * 100 as int)/100.0 as range_start, (1 + cast(z * 100 as int))/100.0  as range_end,
       count(*)
from table t
group by cast(z * 100 as int);
```

Actually turning the range start and range end into a string (such as `'[0.01-0.02]'`) requires string manipulations that, alas, depend on the particular database, which is not specified in the question.